# pouchDB allDocs returns undefined

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I want to get only user documents from db with prefix of us::.
When i run the code below i get the $scope.userList as undefined.
when i `console.log` with in the service i see the array of objects.

how do I return data?

```
$scope.usersList = $pouchDB.getAllDocs('us::');





.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", function($rootScope, $q) {

.........
    this.getAllDocs= function(field){
            database.allDocs({
                  include_docs: true,
                  attachments: true,
                  startkey: field,
                  endkey: field && '\uffff'
            }).then(function (result) {

                console.log(result);
                return result;

            }).catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  });
          };


...
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nlawson comment lead me to answer, i researched many posts on promises and this is what worked for me.

Any feedback to improve my coding is greatly appreciated!

within my controller:

```
if ($stateParams.documentId) {
            $scope.inputForm = {};
            $scope.usersList = [];
            $pouchDB.get($stateParams.documentId).then(function (result) {
                result.woDate = new Date(result.woDate);
                $scope.inputForm = result;
                $scope.inputForm.prId = $stateParams.prId;
                return $pouchDB.getAllDocs('us::');
            }).then(function(udata){
                    $scope.usersList = udata.rows;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                    //do something with err
            });
        }
```

my service is

```
.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", function($rootScope, $q) {
.....
     this.getAllDocs = function(field){
                var data;
                return database.allDocs({
                  include_docs: true,
                  attachments: true,
                  startkey: field,
                  endkey: field && '\uffff'});
      };
.....
}]);
```

Comment: Great! :) You may also find this post useful: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with asynchronous vs synchronous code. You cannot write a function that `return`s the `result`, because `allDocs()` is asynchronous (promise-based).

I suggest reading the [async code guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/async-code.html) to solidify your understanding. In the case of Angular, you're probably going to want to look at how the guides tell you to use the `$http` service, which is also asynchronous and promise-based. I.e. imagine that PouchDB is a remote HTTP server sending you data, and then structure your app around that.

I have an open-source Angular app that uses PouchDB; in my case I used an Angular service. You can check out the code to get some inspiration: [pouchService.js](https://github.com/pouchdb/npm-browser/blob/41a57412d020a8a8acdf91d11deeb113ca39df0d/scripts/services/pouch-service.js).